# Why typescript no detect type errors on read empty elements in array

Tags: typescript

I have something similar to this

```
type User = {
  name: string
}

const arrayUsers: User[] = [];
const aUser = arrayUsers[0]

// this is an error is not detected by TS
console.log(aUser.name)
```

As you can see, I'm trying to read `aUser.name` but `aUser` is undefined.
TS should advise about this error and say that `aUser` could be undefined, but is not.

Here is easy to point out the error, but when you use redux, auto-generated types and API data that could or could not be there, things get pretty crazy.

so, any idea to solve this?

Comment: The compiler assumes that when you index into a type with an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) that the value is defined unless you turn on the [`--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) to get that `undefined`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mblJ3w). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That is completely right! thank you.

Comment: Uh, I guess I could write an answer but do you know if you’d respond in a timely manner?  It’s been more than nine months since you asked this question.